# Which line of code is telling Android to display all images in GalleryView?

Tags: android, image-gallery, galleryview

The following code is a typical way to use `GalleryView` in Android. However, I don't understand which line of code actually display all images 1-8.

I understand that all images 1-8 are stored in the 
array `ImageIds`. However the following code inside `getView{...}` after `@Override` only display one particular image (`ImageIds[position]`) in which `position` is the one you select.

```
i.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
```

Therefore, which line of code is telling Android to display all ImageIds images?

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical">


     <Gallery
         android:id="@+id/gallery1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
         android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_height="250dp"
         android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

      ImageView selectedImage;  
      private Integer[] ImageIds = {
                 R.drawable.image1,
                 R.drawable.image2,
                 R.drawable.image3,
                 R.drawable.image4,
                 R.drawable.image5,
                 R.drawable.image6,
                 R.drawable.image7,
                 R.drawable.image8
         };
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

              Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
         selectedImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         gallery.setSpacing(1);
         gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));

          // clicklistener for Gallery
         gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your selected position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // show the selected Image
                selectedImage.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
             }
         });
     }

 }

GalleryImageAdapter 

 public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
 {
     private Context mContext;

     private Integer[] ImageIds = {
             R.drawable.image1,
             R.drawable.image2,
             R.drawable.image3,
             R.drawable.image4,
             R.drawable.image5,
             R.drawable.image6,
             R.drawable.image7,
             R.drawable.image8
     };

     public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) 
     {
         mContext = context;
     }

     public int getCount() {
         return ImageIds.length;
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }


     // Override this method according to your need
     public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
     {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

         i.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
         i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));

         i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

         return i;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setAdapter` method of the `Gallery` calls all the callback methods of the adapter that u've supplied in it as the parameter.

That is,

```
gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));
```

calls your `GalleryImageAdapter`, which internally calls its `getView()` the number of times that you've given in the `getCount` method.

```
public int getCount() {
    return ImageIds.length;
}
```

will call the `getView()` method `ImageIds.length` number of times.

Comment: Thanks! That is the answer I want! Thanks for your super clear answer. I love it.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
```

in your adapter sets the images from your image-array to your adapter. As you call

```
ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
i.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
```

and

```
gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));
```

sets your adapter to your gallery.

Comment: This line sets the adapter to gallery only. My question is how the gallery knows all images 1-8 are need to be displayed. Thanks.

Comment: Still not clear! Are you telling me that public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)

Comment: This line "public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)" sets the images from your image-array to your adapter? Still not clear

Comment: when you apply adapter to the gallery, gallery calls adapters getView to create the list, and in getView you create an imageView and assign an image to it

Answer (score 0):

When android needs to show a particular page, It will call getView method to get UI for that page. As you move through all pages, getView will be called for corresponding positions i.e. 1, 2, 3 ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have marked in `BaseAdapter`'s unimplemented methods, there is `getCount` method. As we are doing code in `for` loop, same functionality is also here.

`getCount` will return length of array and it will execute from first element of your array to length you have provided in your `getCount` method which is following.

```
public int getCount() {
     return ImageIds.length;
}
```